# How to handle chunks in Web Audio API and Binaryjs with node

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, streaming, web-audio-api

I'm trying to build an audio stream server with Binaryjs and a simple HTML client, this is my Node server setup:

```
var BinaryServer = require('binaryjs').BinaryServer;
var fs = require('fs');
// Start Binary.js server
var server = BinaryServer({port: 9000}); //,chunkSize:150000
// Wait for new user connections
server.on('connection', function(client){
  var file = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/testsong.mp3');
  client.send(file);
  var chunks = [];

  file.on('data', function(data){
    console.log(client._socket._socket._writableState.finished);
    if (chunks.length < 40) {
      chunks.push(data);
    } else {
      if (client._socket._socket._writableState.finished === false) {
        console.log("Send");
        client.send(Buffer.concat(chunks));
      }
      chunks = [];
    }   
  });
});
```

It loads 40 chunks and then sends them back to the connected user. And this is my index.html

```
<html>
  <script src="binaryjs.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
  var client = new BinaryClient('ws://localhost:9000');
  window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
  var context = new AudioContext();
  var delayTime = 0;
  var init = 0;
  var audioStack = [];
  var nextTime = 0;

  client.on('stream', function(stream, meta){
    stream.on('data', function(data) {
      context.decodeAudioData(data, function(buffer) {
        audioStack.push(buffer);

        //Not sure if this line works.
        //  if ((init!=0) || (audioStack.length > 10)) { // make sure we put at least 10 chunks in the buffer before starting
        init++;
        scheduleBuffers();
        //   }
      }, 
      function(err) {
        console.log("err(decodeAudioData): "+err);
      });
    });
  });

  function scheduleBuffers() {
    while ( audioStack.length) {
      var buffer = audioStack.shift();
      var source    = context.createBufferSource();
      source.buffer = buffer;
      source.connect(context.destination);
      if (nextTime == 0) {
        nextTime = context.currentTime + 0.05;  /// add 50ms latency to work well across systems - tune this if you like
      }
      source.start(nextTime);
      nextTime+=source.buffer.duration; // Make the next buffer wait the length of the last buffer before being played
    };
  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The code partially works, the songs start playing but the constantly stop, fuzz. I think the problem is that some chunks are getting played to early and others to late. Already tested changing the latency and changing chunkSize, chunkLength before sending and lots of other codes.

I have also read that the Web Audio API has several faults or I'm not knowing how to implement it, the context.decodeAudioData() throws always the same amount of `null` errors for a song.

Is there a way to adjust it to make it play correctly or what can I do? The decoding seems to partially work so maybe a better latency (already tried changing it).